# maxconn limit per backend in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Our haproxy loadbalancer opens thousands of connections to its backends
even though its settings say to open no more than 10 connections per server instance (see below). When I uncomment "option http-server-close"  the number of backend connection drops however I would like to have keep-alive backend connections.

Why maxconn is not respected with `http-keep-alive`? I verified with `ss` that the opened backend connections are in `ESTABLISHED` state.

```
defaults
     log global
     mode    http
     option http-keep-alive
     timeout http-keep-alive 60000
     timeout connect 6000
     timeout client  60000
     timeout server  20000


 frontend http_proxy
     bind    *:80
     default_backend backends

 backend backends
     option prefer-last-server

     # option http-server-close
     timeout http-keep-alive 1000
     server s1 10.0.0.21:8080 maxconn 10
     server s2 10.0.0.7:8080  maxconn 10
     server s3 10.0.0.22:8080 maxconn 10
     server s4 10.0.0.16:8080 maxconn 10
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're hitting the same problem in our service.

Comment: When you say "Why maxconn is not respected with http-keep-alive" do you mean `timeout http-keep-alive` or `option http-keep-alive`?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110899/maxconn-limit-per-backend-in-haproxy and https://leo-project.net/leofs/docs/admin/system_admin/load_balancing/